# Как добавить условие в цикл?

Tags: java, циклы, for

Есть код ниже с циклом. Мне необходимо проверить переменную String uuid на соответствие со значениями в массиве storage. Я хочу добавить условие когда !storage[number].getUuid().equals(uuid) и чтобы при выполнении условия выводилась надпись но не могу додуматься куда прикрутить его. Помогите пожалуйста. Переменная size должна уменьшаться каждый раз когда мы находим совпадение

```
public void delete(String uuid) {
        int number = 0;
        for (number = 0; number < size; number++) {
            if (storage[number].getUuid().equals(uuid)) {
                for (int j = number; j < size; j++) {
                    storage[j] = storage[j + 1];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        size--;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь. Anastasiya помогла додуматься до применения boolean Я решил это так :

```
`   public void delete(String uuid) {
        int number = 0;
        boolean isEquals = false;
        for (number = 0; number < size; number++) {
            if (storage[number].getUuid().equals(uuid)) {
                for (int j = number; j < size; j++) {
                    storage[j] = storage[j + 1];
                }
                isEquals = true;
                if (isEquals) {
                    size--;
                }
               
            }
        }
        if (!isEquals) {
            System.out.println("This resume does not exist");
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 3):

Вместо цикла проще использовать стрим:

```
boolean isEquals = Arrays.asStream(uuidArray)
.map(a ->a.getUuid())
.anyMatch(a -> a.equals(uuid));

if(!isEquals) {
    System.out.println(..);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Красиво. Пока такие метода ни разу не применял

Comment: @Kekcoe Посмотрите Stream API, лямбды и функциональные интерфейсы - почти никогда не придется что-то выдумывать с циклами

Comment: вообще я подумал, что тут наверное   не очень удобно применять ваш метод. Потому что у меня массив хранит экземпляры класса с полем String uuid поэтому чтобы иcпользовать stream мне надо будет создавать временный массив String.
for(int i = 0: i<size;i++){
temp[i] = storage[i].getUuid
}
Но мне я многократно буду менять переменную size. Поэтому может как то можно обойтись циклами?

Comment: @Kekcoe не представляю зачем вам копировать массив в другой массив) ```Arrays.asStream(array)``` принимает любой массив на вход. Если хотите скопировать, проще будет сделать ```newArray = System.arrayCopy(oldArray);``` Если ваш массив переменной длины - используйте ```List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();``` из него так же можно получить стрим - ```list.stream().anyMatch(uuid);``` Если читаете с пользовательского ввода - ```String[] array = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+"); ```

Comment: И с помощью стрима, можете заполнить рандомными значеиями свой массив - ```String[] array = IntStream.range(1(from), 10(to)).peek(i -> UUID.randomUUID.toString).toArray();```

Comment: я имею ввиду, что мой метод delete принимает на вход String и я должен сравнить его со String ом экземпляров класса, которые лежат в массиве. Коллекции я не могу использовать, так установлено заданием. Я может изначально все детали не написал. я тока учусь.

Comment: @Kekcoe Поняла, поправила в решении

Answer (score 1):

> Я хочу добавить условие когда !storage[number].getUuid().equals(uuid)

В коде уже есть противоположное условие, поэтому все, что нужно сделать, это добавить к нему ветку else

```
if (storage[number].getUuid().equals(uuid)) {
    for (int j = number; j < size; j++) {
        storage[j] = storage[j + 1];
   } else {
    //выводите надпись
}
```

Comment: Но в этом случае если не выполниться условие то переменная size  уменьшится. size должна уменьшаться в случае выполнения условия storage[number].getUuid().equals(uuid)

Comment: ну так перенесите изменение переменной внутрь нужной ветки

Comment: с этим у меня проблема так как если я size перенесу в if то она станет не доступной " Unreachable statement"

Comment: После break, что ли, ставите?